# Kafka Streams program is throwing exceptions when producing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running a program using Kafka Streams. But my program is throwing below exceptions after running some time. Please help me to slove the issue.

```
2017-11-21 09:58:59,947 ERROR c.e.s.c.f.k.s.p.Sample[sample-app-0.0.1-3675e4df-5e08-466e-98fe-c4f92d24df89-StreamThread-1] task [2_0] exception caught when producing org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [2_0] exception caught when producing
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.checkForException(RecordCollectorImpl.java:136)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.flush(RecordCollectorImpl.java:144)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commitImpl(StreamTask.java:259)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:253)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:815)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$2800(StreamThread.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$2.apply(StreamThread.java:797)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.performOnStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:1448)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:789)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:778)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:567)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 10 record(s) for sample-0: 31894 ms has passed since last append
```

Comment: Can u provide few more details like program snippet and configuration?

Comment: This is a know bug in in the `KafkaProducer`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5886 -- There is only one workaround by increasing the request timeout -- however, because this parameter affect *all* requests, it might have a large impact and should change it only with care.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Exceptions are not identified by configuring request.timeout.ts with 120 seconds.